# RadioGroup buttons getting set to default on scroll

Tags: android, radio-group

I have an array adapter in android that adapts a bunch of different surveys that are made up of SurveyQuestion objects into a listview.

I initially had the problem where views were being recycled and answers showed up everywhere, but now i've fixed that.

However every time I scroll past the question it gets set to the default answer again when I scroll back.

How do I stop this from happening?

SurveyAdapter:

```
public class SurveyCTAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SurveyQuestion> {
private final Context context;//needs a way to put in check boxes
private final List<SurveyQuestion> objects;
int[] rdioIDs;

public SurveyCTAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SurveyQuestion> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    rdioIDs = new int[7];
    rdioIDs[0] = R.id.r1;
    rdioIDs[1] = R.id.r2;
    rdioIDs[2] = R.id.r3;
    rdioIDs[3] = R.id.r4;
    rdioIDs[4] = R.id.r5;
    rdioIDs[5] = R.id.r6;
    rdioIDs[6] = R.id.r7;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(objects.get(position).rowID, null);
        RadioGroup rdiogrp = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rdiogrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radio, int isChecked) {
                View radioButton = radio.findViewById(isChecked);
                int radioId = radio.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radio.getChildAt(radioId);
                String selection = (String) btn.getText();
                SurveyQuestion question = (SurveyQuestion) radio.getTag();
                int index = question.buttonNames.indexOf(selection);

                if(index>=0){
                question.currentAns=index;
                Log.d("index",""+index);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    String question = objects.get(position).question;
    name.setText(question);
    RadioGroup rdiogrp = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    for(int i=0; i<objects.get(position).buttonNames.size(); i++){
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) rdiogrp.findViewById(rdioIDs[i]);
        radioButton.setText(objects.get(position).buttonNames.get(i));
    }
    RadioButton rdiobtn = (RadioButton) rdiogrp.findViewById(rdioIDs[objects.get(position).currentAns]);
    rdiobtn.setChecked(true);
    Log.d("position",""+position);
    rdiogrp.setTag((objects).get(position));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

And SurveyQuestion:

```
public class SurveyQuestion {
public String question;
public int rowID;
public ArrayList<String> buttonNames;
public HashMap<String, Integer> answerValue;
public int currentAns=0;
public boolean needTextBox;

public SurveyQuestion(String question, boolean b){
    this.question=question;
    this.needTextBox = b;
    answerValue = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

public SurveyQuestion(String question, int ID){
    this.question=question;
    this.rowID = ID;
    this.needTextBox = false;
    answerValue = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

}

public SurveyQuestion(String question, int ID, ArrayList<String> names){
    this.question=question;
    this.rowID=ID;
    this.buttonNames = names;
    this.needTextBox = false;
    answerValue = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

}
public int getScore(){
    return answerValue.get(buttonNames.get(currentAns));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need to be storing your questions in the tags of the views. I feel that this may be part of the issue. What I usually do in this scenario is store an Integer index in the tag of a view that is actionable in a ListView. In the listener then use the index tag to retrieve the object from your ArrayAdapter using `getItem(int)`.

Comment: I've tried that as well but it doesn't work. It looks as though once i scroll the onCheckedChange gets called again and sets the index back to 0

Comment: Well you've got a list of Questions in the ArrayAdapter, another private list in your class SurveyCTAAdapter and individual questions stored in tags on your views. Try clean that up so that you only use the internal ArrayAdapter data and use `getItem(int)` to retrieve and modify Questions. That'll put you in the right direction to solving this issue.

Comment: Oh my god as soon as I did that I was able to figure out what was going on. Thank you so much.